# imageprocessing obtaining histogram from patches matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have an image of size (H,W). 
I would like to get histograms of each patch of size [N,N] from that image.
These patches should have half overlap.
What is the fast way to do it?

If I use `blockproc` in Matlab I think I won't be able to get overlapping patches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `blockproc` for overlapping blocks. just use the `'BorderSize'` property.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please give me an example code? I have a problem when implementing it. please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386309/blockproc-matlab-with-bordersize